# Can xPath in LibXML be regex type

Tags: regex, perl, xpath, libxml2

We usually write our Search Path in `findnodes()` function as below

```
//parentNode[subNode/text() = 'CPUUSAGE']/subNode
```

what is I want to match a part of the text here and find all the nodes?

something like

```
//parentNode[subNode/text() =~ '/CPUUSAGE'/]/subNode
```

Obviously this is Invalid xPath...

Any thoughts how to achieve this?

I know I can first find the nodes and then try to match the `textContent`. But Can we do that in one shot directly in `findnodes()`?

Answer (score 2):

XPath 1.0 (which `libxml` implements) doesn’t include any built-in support for regular expressions. In the example you give, which uses a fairly simple regular expression, you could use the [`contains` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) to achieve a similar result:

```
//parentNode[subNode[contains(text(), 'CPUUSAGE')]]/subNode
```

(As an aside that’s an odd expression – you’d probably really want something like `//parentNode/subNode[contains(text(), 'CPUUSAGE')]` but I realise it’s just an example.)

There are some other [string functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) that could be useful in creating other simple queries.

You could create your own custom XPath function to filter nodes based on a regular expression, in fact the docs for the Perl LibXML module includes an [example of doing just that](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0112/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pod#Custom_XPath_functions).

XPath 2.0 does have support for using regular expressions with a [group of string functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#string.match). Unless you have an XPath 2.0 processor that will not be too useful.

Answer (score 0):

[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/search?q=XML%3A%3ATwig) has support for regular expressions in its xpaths.

The following is an xpath that I used in an answer to this SO question: [`Updating xml attribute value based on other with Perl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543570/updating-xml-attribute-value-based-on-other-with-perl)

```
project[string(path) =~ /\bopensource\b/]/revision
```

I also created a second answer so that I could experiment with how `XML::LibXML` could be used to solve the same problem, and in that case I just iterated over all projects and did the regex filtering manually.